# Using Shared Preferences in Java to store a int variable

Tags: java

I am trying to use Shared Preferences in Java to store a variable so that any time I run the program it will retain its count. I am just not sure how to use it. Do I need to create the Share Preferences class or can I use it for example my code looks like this.

```
 if(action.equals ("insert")
 {
 int booking_id = (initially be zero);
 booking_id += 1; 
 // I want booking Id to retain its value and not become zero the next time I run it.

 }
```

Comment: Store your bookindId in a file or database if you want to do this.

Comment: @tieTYT Wow thanks for the link.. never knew that there is a package like`java.util.prefs` for such things as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean Shared Preferences as available in Android.

You would want to ask the SharedPreferences for the value of `booking_id`:

```
SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int booking_id = pref.getInt("booking_id", 0); // 0 is the default value if the preferences do not find the "booking_id"
```